# TeX, free floating, anchors

Tags: diagrams

I want to achieve the following:

1. I want a single page to consist of N "regions."

   Each region has a x-start, y-start, and a `\hbox` (denoting the contents of the region).
2. Furthermore, for each region, I want to be able to define "anchors" within the reason.
3. I want to be able to draw arrows pointing from one anchor to another anchor.

What is the best way to achieve this in TeX?

Comment: If they are floating then what does `x-start`, `y-start` represent?

Comment: Sounds like a classical box-and-pointer diagram to me, so TikZ would be the canonical answer. If you describe a little more what the diagram should look like (or show an example), more detailed advice can be given.

Comment: The tags on this are definitely wrong.

Comment: I want to specify the x and y coordinates.

Comment: My point was if you are specifying the `x` and `y` coordinates then they are not floating, they are a fixed spot on the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way to do it with, what else, but `tikz`:

[image]

The content is placed with

```
\AnchoredRegion[<draw options>]{<name of region>}{x,y}{<content>}
```

where:

- `<draw options>` is an optional parameter used to style the box. If you don't want the box, you can use `fill=none`. If you want a solid box use `draw=<color>`, etc...
- `<name of region>` is the name given to this node which can later be used to reference it's location
- `x,y` is the `x` and `y` offset form the south west corner of the page.  The units for this default to `cm`, but if you prefer other unit you can provide them. For example `{1in,1in}` would be equivalent to `{2.54cm,2.54cm}` or `{2.54,2.54}`.
- `<content>` is the content that is to be placed

After the boxes are placed then you can draw line from one to the other as desired with:

```
\DrawLines[<draw options>]{<name of region>}{<name of region>}
```

Only a very small subset of the options that are avilable are illustrated here. For other draw options one should refer to the `tikz/pgf` user manual.

### Note:

- This does require two runs. First one to determine the locations, and the second to do the drawing.
- Note that no test is made to ensure you are no overlapping boxes. So, if that is not desired, you may need to tweak the `x`, `y` coordinates of the locations of these `tikz` nodes.

---

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\AnchoredRegion}[4][]{%
    % #1= draw options
    % #2= name of this node
    % #3= x,y offset from south west of current page
    % #4= content for node
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture, outer sep=0, inner sep=5pt]
        \node [#1] (#2) at
            ($(current page.south west)+(#3)$)
            {#4};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\newcommand{\DrawLines}[3][]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture, outer sep=0, inner sep=5pt]
        \draw [ultra thick, #1] (#2) to (#3);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}%

\newcommand*{\TextA}{\parbox{3.0cm}{\raggedright Some small text over two lines.}}%
\newcommand*{\TextB}{\parbox{3.0cm}{\raggedright Some longer piece of text that takes up three lines.}}%
\newcommand*{\TextC}{\parbox{3.0cm}{\raggedright Some even longer piece of text thatjust goes on and on and on and on..... Well you get the idea.}}%

\begin{document}
    \AnchoredRegion[fill=yellow!40]{YellowRegion}{7,7}{\TextA}
    \AnchoredRegion[fill=cyan!40]{BlueRegion}{7,10}{\TextB}
    \AnchoredRegion[fill=orange!40]{OrangeRegion}{7,13}{\TextC}
    \AnchoredRegion[fill=red!20]{RedRegion}{11,13}{\TextC}

    \DrawLines[out=130,in=-130,-stealth, red]
            {YellowRegion.west}{OrangeRegion.west}
    \DrawLines[out=30,in=-90,-stealth, brown, dotted]
            {YellowRegion.east}{RedRegion.south}
    \DrawLines[-stealth, violet]{BlueRegion.south}
            {YellowRegion.north}
    \DrawLines[out=-150,in=120, distance=6cm, -stealth, green]
            {YellowRegion.south}{OrangeRegion.north}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I haven't tested, but I assume TeX has to be run twice for this to work? If yes, maybe you should add a remark to your answer.

Comment: @StephanLehmke: Thanks. That is part of my usual answers, but missed it this time -- perhaps because I removed `\tikzmark` as it was not needed. Have updated solution.

Comment: Amazing. I like.